# Pandas astype int not removing decimal points from values

Tags: python, pandas

I tried converting the values in some columns of a DataFrame of floats to integers by using round then astype. However, the values still contained decimal places. What is wrong with my code?

```
nums = np.arange(1, 11)
arr = np.array(nums)
arr = arr.reshape((2, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df += 0.1
df
```

Original df:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1
1   6.1 7.1 8.1 9.1 10.1
```

Rounding then to int code:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].round()
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(int)
df
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1.1 2.1 3.0 4.0 5.0
1   6.1 7.1 8.0 9.0 10.0
```

Expected output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1.1 2.1 3   4   5
1   6.1 7.1 8   9   10
```

Comment: pandas seems to be cautious. It won't downcast columns when setting values (so because float can hold int is stays float) but it will upcast the type when necessary (i.e. would change to object if you tried to set it to values that were string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is for the `.iloc` it assign the value and did not change the column type

```
l = df.columns[2:]
df[l] = df[l].astype(int)
df
     0    1  2  3   4
0  1.1  2.1  3  4   5
1  6.1  7.1  8  9  10
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve that is to use `.convert_dtypes()`

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].round()
df = df.convert_dtypes()
print(df)
```

output:

```
     0    1  2  3   4
0  1.1  2.1  3  4   5
1  6.1  7.1  8  9  10
```

It will help you to coerce all dtypes of your dataframe to a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, was able to resolve with converting numbers to str and applying an lambda to cut of zeros.

```
df['converted'] = df['floats'].astype(str)
def cut_zeros(row):
  if row[-2:]=='.0':
    row=row[:-2]
  else:row
  return row
df['converted'] = df.apply(lambda row: cut_zeros(row['converted']),axis=1)
```